# Sqlite_prepare_v2 return SQLite_ERROR

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, syntax-error

I have to open a table from a SQLite database that has some empty fields, so, after giving the name of the table to open and the database address in the documents folder (all right), I set the query, and then I used the function `sqlite_prepare_v2` to prepare the extraction of data but returns the value `1` (`SQLite_ERROR`)  and gives a syntax error. Why? I wrote the fields names right.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)loadDatiFromTable:(NSString*) nameTable {

    NSString *query =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id,title, ifnull(IMAGES,''),ifnull(text, ''), ifnull(NUMBER, ''),ifnull(CAP, 0) FROM %@ order by ID", nameTable];  
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement,nil);
    NSLog(@"The value is %d", sqlResult); // here sqlResult is 1

    if (sqlResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            //......
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed from sqlite3_step(statement). Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        // here return: "Failed from sqlite3_step(statement). Error is:  near "NUMBER": syntax error"
       sqlite3_close(database);
   }

   return self.tableArray;
}


-(id) initWithTable:(NSString*)nomeTabella withDbPath: (NSString *)dbPath { 
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed open database");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"OPEN DATABASE");
            [self loadDatiFromTable:nomeTabella ];
        }

        return self;
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
    "Failed from sqlite3_step(statement). Error is:  near "NUMBER": syntax error"
```

Comment: I've edited your code to improve readability.

Comment: Could you post the exact error from your log and the create TABLE script for the table you are querying? It might give some added insight for those looking to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"NUMBER"` instead of `NUMBER` to ensure that this word is not interpreted as an SQL keyword.